Passing input into a running netcat session in python
I'm doing a CTF task, I'm using netcat to write to a server. The server asks me for input and then gives me some output based on what I pass in.
I need to make a python script that automates this, meaning that it executes the nc command, which is easy enough
system("nc 192.168.0.100 55555")

But now what? I need to pass the input into it and then receive the output and react respectively.
How can I do this?

use subprocess module instead. you can pass input to its functions like .run().
